# WebApplication Response

Tags: web-applications

I just wanted to know when a client browser hits a url of a web application how does the web app send the response exactly back to the client browser/machine. I know the Ip address and other details have to be stored some place. How does this happen? Are there any links i could refer to?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

your client browser sends request in form of [`HTTP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) request, which is a protocol (set of (here *communication*) rules), traveled on TCP/IP

Comment: Yes, so the web server will somewhere preserve the address details right?

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

This is the generic description - if your question is indeed related to Java, you can also read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servlet.

The "IP address and other details" do not have to be stored anywhere on the server according to any of the specifications - but they often are by the web server, because it's useful information...

Specifically:

- **Browser** opens TCP connection to server (usually on port 80, or port 443 for SSL)
- **Browser** sends HTTP request to server (see wikipedia link for examples) using TCP connection
- **Server** interprets HTTP request
- **Server** responds using TCP connection; response complies with HTTP specification
- **Browser** receives response (over TCP connection) and renders it for the end user

As part of "server interprets HTTP request", the server may choose to store any and all data associated with the request - including the IP address which opened the connection, and any meta data associated with the HTTP request.

Comment: Yes i think so too, so the server would use this info to send back the response..